# Getting rid of non-unique entries in an adjacency list

Tags: c++, maze, adjacency-list

I'm currently working on a project for my upper-level C++ class, and we are building a program that makes a maze, then solves it, the makes a PNG of said maze. Pretty cool stuff. Anyways, I'm current on the bit where I need to make the maze.
My program makes valid mazes just fine, but I have to make each number output unique. The output just spits out two indicies in a 2d matrix that have walls between them, sample output for a 3X4 maze is as follows:

> rjeffor1:hydra20 ~/cs302/labs/lab5> ./mazemake 3 4         <-  9:49AM
>
> 1 2
>
> 1 5
>
> 2 1
>
> 2 3
>
> 3 2
>
> 5 1
>
> 5 9
>
> 6 7
>
> 7 6
>
> 8 9
>
> 9 8
>
> 9 5

However, my last problem is that I need to get rid of duplicate walls, for example 1 2 and 2 1. EDIT: and by this I mean just get rid of the 2 1, I still need the wall and therefore the 1 2.

Here is my function in which I attempt to fix the problem:

```
void aL::make_unique()
{
    vector<int>::iterator it, it0;

    //need to iterate thru all but last index

    for (int i=0; i<(int)adjList.size()-1; i++) {

        for (int j=0; j<(int)adjList.size(); j++) {

            //find it

            if (i!=j) {
                it0 = std::find(adjList[i].begin(), adjList[i].end(), j);
                it = std::find(adjList[j].begin(), adjList[j].end(), i);
                if (it!=adjList[j].end() && it!=adjList[j].end())
                    //erase it if anything is there
                    adjList[j].erase(it);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Help is appreciated, my brain is so done at this point

EDIT: here is how I populate the adjancency lists, based on indicies directly left right above and below each index

```
aL::aL (const int &rows, const int &cols)
{
    adjList.resize(rows*cols);
    //run thru and figure out where indicies AREN'T
    //to fill in their adjacency list
    for (int i=0; i<(int)adjList.size(); i++) {
        //if not on the left edge
        if (i%cols!=0)
            adjList[i].push_back(i-1);
        //not on the right edge
        if ((i+1)%cols!=0)
            adjList[i].push_back(i+1);
        //not on the top edge
        if (i>=cols)
            adjList[i].push_back(i-cols);
        //not on the bottom edge
        if (i<(rows*cols)-cols)
            adjList[i].push_back(i+cols);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of adjList?

Comment: @metalhead vector<vector<int> >

Comment: That helps a little, but I'm still confused about how your adjList is populated and how they correspond to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the need to post-process and make it unique at the end if you check as you are adding to your list. Don't add "a b" if "b a" is already there.

Comment: Because of the nature of the assignment, the way my program has to work is that everything has a wall between it, and then I "knock down" (get rid of entries) walls and then print the results